# Alter object value base on object value

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Below is the result of my `console.log(myJson)`

```
[{"placeholdId":1,"itemId":null,"type":null},
{"placeholdId":2,"itemId":null,"type":null},
{"placeholdId":3,"itemId":null,"type":null},
{"placeholdId":4,"itemId":null,"type":null},
{"placeholdId":5,"itemId":5,"type":"food"},
{"placeholdId":6,"itemId":null,"type":"null"}]
```

how can I set the value of my object value base on the placeholdId? for example the 5th item, I want to change the itemId and type to null as well.

I'm stuck until here..

```
var obj = $.parseJSON(json);
console.log(obj[4]);
```

Comment: Try: `obj[4]['itemId'] = null;` Or if you don't know what order they're in then loop through the array checking for `obj[i]['placeholdId'] === 5`.

Comment: @bloodyKnuckles after checking what should I do? I want to change other values not the placeholdId